# My sudoku solver program enters an infinite loop and I don't see why [python]

Tags: python, recursion, sudoku

canPlaceTile method works as it should so I doubt the problem is in it. Also, the row count never goes beyond 2

```
def canSolve(board, col, row):

    if col == len(board[row]):
        
        row += 1
        col = 0
        if row == len(board):
            for i in board:
                print(*i)
            return True
    
    
    if board[row][col] != 0:
        canSolve(board, col + 1, row)
   
    for num in range(1,10):
        if canPlaceTile(board, col, row, num):
            board[row][col] = num
            if canSolve(board, col + 1, row):
                return True
        board[row][col] = 0
    return False
```

Comment: do you mean to `return canSolve` in that second if statement?

Comment: As @Sayse denoted, your second `if` statement is causing infinite recursion.

Comment: Did you try a small test case like `[[1, 0], [0, 2]]`? I think problem is not infinite recursion, but huge volume of computation, making it look like infinite recursion. By adding `return` as pointed out by @Sayse, complexity is roughly _O(9^(number of 0s))_ and without it _O(9^(9 * 9))_.

Comment: @Sayse that fixed the infinite loop but for some reason row still doesn't go higher than 2